# Xcode: Compile Under Certain Build Configurations

Tags: xcode, build, compilation, xcode3.2

Is there a way to configure a given target to only compile under certain build configurations?

For example, let's say I have a simple shell tool that compiles alongside a larger library to test it.  Can I set it to compile under the "Debug" build configuration, but not "Release?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is something like

```
#ifdef RELEASE
 // if we get here it won't compile
 #error
#endif
```

I know that's quite dirty, I do apologize - hopefully someone more experience in Xcode/Objective-C will have an answer!

Comment: This works for my purposes, since I really just need to make sure my library links properly.  I'll wait to see if there's a cleaner solution before accepting this as the answer, though.